# Type mismatch (runtime error 13)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to locate a certain date in another worksheet

I am getting a mismatch error on this line

```
dateFound = .Find(chosenDate, LookIn = xlValues)
```

I declare my variables as follow:

```
Dim chosenDate As String
Dim dateFound As String
```

Any help would be appreciate,

Thanks.

Comment: Find returns a range.  dateFound should be `Dim dateFound as Range`

Comment: even when I declare it as a Range I still get the same error.

Comment: You may have to set it. not sure.  `Set dateFound = .Find(chosenDate, LookIn = xlValues)`

Comment: If find returns a range, you definitely have to set it. However, you can try dateFound = .Find(chosenDate, LookIn = xlValues).Value

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing a colon there ... `dateFound = .Find(chosenDate, LookIn := xlValues)`

Also, in passing argument into a named argument (i.e. using the `:=`), you must also provide the argument name for chosenDate that is the `What:=`

So the correct complete syntax is

```
dateFound = .Find(What:=chosenDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Meaning you either provide all the argument names; or omit all and use commas to place the inputs such as

```
datefound = .Find(choosenDate,,,xlValues)
```

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527(v=vs.60).aspx